# How to get record based on current month and year from timestamp column in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How to get record based on current month and year from timestamp column in oracle? I have column in table named payment_time. I want to apply filter on this column  based on current month and year.
My payment_time column is in this timestamp format.

```
20200103161803
```

Attachment is also attached for [image: reference]

Comment: Why aren't you using a `timestamp` column for this?

Comment: What exactly is the data type of your column?

Comment: column type is varchar2(50)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to get record based on current month and year from timestamp column in oracle?

Use a filter on your `TIMESTAMP` column to set the upper and lower bounds. For the lower bound you can `TRUNC`ate the current date to the start of the month and for the upper bound you can do the same and add a month:

```sql
SELECT payment_time
FROM   CPDB_TEST_REPORTS.T_X_G2P_EXE_REPORT_N
WHERE  G2PORG_SHORTCODE = '00164752'
AND    payment_time >= TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' )
AND    payment_time <  ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), 1 )
```

You could also use `TRUNC` on the `payment_time` column (however, then Oracle would not use an index on the `payment_time` column and would need a separate function-based index on `TRUNC( payment_time )`):

```sql
SELECT payment_time
FROM   CPDB_TEST_REPORTS.T_X_G2P_EXE_REPORT_N
WHERE  G2PORG_SHORTCODE = '00164752'
AND    TRUNC( payment_time, 'MM' ) >= TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' )
```

If your `payment_time` column is not actually a `TIMESTAMP` data type but is a `VARCHAR2` then you can use exactly the same technique and just convert the filter values to a string of numbers:

```sql
SELECT payment_time
FROM   CPDB_TEST_REPORTS.T_X_G2P_EXE_REPORT_N
WHERE  G2PORG_SHORTCODE = '00164752'
AND    payment_time >= TO_CHAR( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' )
AND    payment_time <  TO_CHAR( ADD_MONTHS( TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'MM' ), 1 ), 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS' )
```

Comment: get this exception [22008][1861] ORA-01861: literal does not match format string Position: 122

Comment: @ImranHussain Updated .... but you should fix your table to store date/time data using the `DATE` or `TIMESTAMP` data types and not as strings or numbers.

Comment: Actually i am using 3 party view